# Create Child <li> items if LEFT OUTER JOIN finds rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble dragging mysql data out into a required HTML format, i'll try to give a simplified example of what I have / need:

**Example Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcat` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` text NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblsubcat` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subcatname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

**Example Data:**

```
INSERT INTO `tblcat` (`id`, `catname`, `comments`, `enabled`) VALUES
(100, 'Bells & Horns', '', 0),
(101, 'Bottles & Bottle Cages', '', 0),
(216, 'Brake Blocks - Shimano', '', 0),
(243, 'Brake Discs & Accessories', '', 0)

INSERT INTO `tblsubcat` (`id`, `subcatname`, `catid`, `enabled`) VALUES
(194, 'Bottom Bracket Axles', 102, 0),
(204, 'Bottom Bracket Parts', 102, 0)
```

**Target HTML:**

```
<li><a href="viewproducts.php?task=showsubs&catID=100">Bells & Horns</a></li>
<li><a href="viewproducts.php?task=showsubs&catID=101">Bottles & Bottle Cages</a></li>
<li>
<a href="viewproducts.php?task=refine&catID=102" class="extends">Bottom Brackets & Accessories</a>
<ul class="subcategory">
  <li><a href="viewproducts.php?task=refine&catID=102&subcatID=194">Bottom Bracket Axles</a></li>
  <li><a href="viewproducts.php?task=refine&catID=102&subcatID=204">Bottom Bracket Parts</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="viewproducts.php?task=showsubs&catID=216">Brake Blocks - Shimano</a></li>
<li><a href="viewproducts.php?task=showsubs&catID=243">Brake Discs & Accessories</a></li>
```

**My Attempt so far:**

```
$CurrentCatID = 0;
$Categories = mysql_query("SELECT tblcat.id as CatID, tblcat.catname as CatName, IFNULL(tblsubcat.id, -1) as SubCatID, IFNULL(tblsubcat.subcatname, '') as SubCatName FROM tblcat LEFT OUTER JOIN tblsubcat ON tblcat.id = tblsubcat.catid WHERE tblcat.enabled = '0' ORDER BY tblcat.catname ASC, tblsubcat.subcatname ASC");  
$CurrentCatID = mysql_result($Categories, 0, "CatID");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Categories)) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"viewproducts.php?task=showsubs&catID=" . $row["CatID"] . "\">" . htmlspecialchars($row["CatName"]) . "</a></li>";
}
```

How can I extend the above PHP to create the Target HTML outlined above? I've tried all sorts of convoluted looping backwards and forwards methods which are fugly & I'm sure there must be a cleaner way of doing it - so thought id ask here :)

**Edit:**

My final working version:

```
$InSub = false;
$PreviousCatID = "";
$Categories = mysql_query("SELECT tblcat.id as CatID, tblcat.catname as CatName, IFNULL(tblsubcat.id, -1) as SubCatID, IFNULL(tblsubcat.subcatname, '') as SubCatName FROM tblcat LEFT OUTER JOIN tblsubcat ON tblcat.id = tblsubcat.catid WHERE tblcat.enabled = '0' ORDER BY tblcat.catname ASC, tblsubcat.subcatname ASC");  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Categories)) {
    if ($InSub === true && ($row["SubCatID"] === "-1" || $PreviousCatID !== $row["CatID"])) {
        echo "  </ul>\n";
        echo "</li>\n";
        $InSub = false;
    }        
    if ($row["SubCatID"] === "-1") {
        echo "<li><a href=\"viewproducts.php?task=showsubs&catID=" . $row["CatID"] . "\">" . htmlspecialchars($row["CatName"]) . "</a></li>\n";  
    } else {
        if ($PreviousCatID !== $row["CatID"] || $InSub === false) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"viewproducts.php?task=showsubs&catID=" . $row["CatID"] . "\" class=\"extends\">" . htmlspecialchars($row["CatName"]) . "</a>\n";
            echo "  <ul class=\"subcategory\">\n";
            $InSub = true;
        }
        echo "    <li><a href=\"viewproducts.php?task=showsubs&catID=" . $row["CatID"] . "&subcatID=" . $row["SubCatID"] . "\">" . htmlspecialchars($row["SubCatName"]) . "</a></li>\n";
    }
    $PreviousCatID = $row["CatID"];
}
```

Comment: I usually create new array in PHP, and then i read SQL results one by one and add them to new array (with subarray if it has subcategories). I don't think there is 'clean' way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaner way of doing the "Attempt so far":

First, I would suggest to take your query and make it a Stored Procedure.  This will clean up your code, AND improve the performance because it will be compiled.

If a SP isn't an option, at least assign the query to a constant value above, and then use mysql_query(CONST_QRY); . . . since you have no variables building the SQL dynamically.

Second, your looping through the result set isn't very "ugly", but you typically don't want to build your "View" or Client Side HTML in the server side code.  You could use JQuery and Ajax to make a request to your server side PHP code, which would then execute the query, and return the results to your client side code to display.

---

**edit**

---

RE your comment, I had misunderstood that part of your question. Sorry.

I would suggest to have a boolean value to tell if you're currently in the sub level.  And another to tell if the last loop iteration was in a sub level.  The below code is conceptual of how that would work.

```
$blnSub = false;
$prevSubId = "";
while(...){
   $blnEndSub = $blnSub;
   $blnSub = ($row["subId"] == null);

   //if not in a sub, but was previously in sub, end the UL
   if($blnSub == false && $blnEndSub == true) {
      echo "</ul>";
   //if in sub but was not previously in sub, start UL
   } else if ($blnSub == true && $blnEndSub == false) {
      echo "<ul>";
   //if in a sub.  previously in sub.  new sub id.
   } else if ($blnSub == true && $blnEndSub == true && $prevSubId != $row["subId"]) {
      echo "</ul><ul>";
   }

   if($blnSub == true) {
        echo "<li class=sub><ahref...etc...></a></li>";
   } else {
        echo "<li><ahref...etc...></a></li>";
   }

   $prevSubId = $row["subId"];
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand, my difficulty (and my question) is how to enumerate the SQL result set & knowing whether or not to open a sub <ul> or not as I loop through it - I.e. I only need to open a sub <ul> if the cat has sub cats or not. Wrapping the SQL in a proc / tidying the code base afterwards isn't a concern at the moment :)

Comment: @HeavenCore Sorry about that, I've edited my post with an attempt to clear that up.

Comment: Many thanks for your revised edit, however; that still fails to account for two lots of sub-cats immediately following each other (in which case the old sub needs closing and a new sub needs opening whenever the CatID changes and SubCatID is !== -1)

Comment: @HeavenCore My oh my. :)  Added a third elseif block to check if was in sub, and again in sub, but a different id.  Also added logic that if its in a sub to use a different class name

Comment: Cheers Adam, your answer helped guide me to a solution - ive edited my question to include my final code - seems to work fine now - cheers.